# How to use between query function in realm database

Tags: android, database, realm, between

I am using realm database for my android app. I wanna know how to use a query called "between" for a string. For example

```
final RealmResults<PersonModel> list = myRealm.
                    where(PersonModel.class).between("name","A","E").findAll();
```

its not working for the string which i have used.But its working only for int types. Can someone please help me.

Comment: following operator couldn't bet applied for String so what u can do to add extra field which could ab an integer so u can use those kind of operations

Comment: Can you give me an example

Answer (score -1):

According to https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html query does not have method between accepting strings as parameters. Between usually can be replaced with pair of less-than and greater-than operators, but those does not support strings as well. So if you want to do between for strings lexicographically, the only way is to exclude between at all and do filtering in java.

Example:

```
final RealmResults<PersonModel> list = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(PersonModel.class).findAll();
Collection<PersonModel> betweenModels = new ArrayList<>();
for (PersonModel m : list) {
    if(m.getName().compareTo("A") >= 0 && m.getName().compareTo("E") <= 0) {
        betweenModels.add(m);
    }
}
```

betweenModels will contain items with names bigger-equal than "A" and less-equal than "E" lexicographically

Comment: Can you give me an example please

Comment: I've added example to answer

Comment: for whoever downvoted my answer, can you provide better (if any) answer or at least explain reason of downvoting?

Comment: Because this can be still represented as a `RealmResults<T>` without having to evaluate the entire result set with Java-side filtering, while eagerly ripping out all elements (thus ruining the lazy-loading property of results).

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, answer suggested by you only works if we are dealing with single character strings (which was not specified in question). Can you edit your answer to support any strings?

Comment: single character? I said `beginsWith` not `equalTo`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, string 'Eee' technically falls outside 'A'..'E' range (according to between semantics), but your solution this string will be included. That is why your answer is not correct.

Comment: You can just put `//` before `.or().beginsWith("name","E")` and it'll work O_o this is a change for which you don't need to put in much thought

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134071/discussion-between-alex-radzishevsky-and-epicpandaforce).

Answer (score -1):

```
final RealmResults<PersonModel> list = myRealm
                  .where(PersonModel.class)
                    .beginsWith("name","A")
                      .or().beginsWith("name","B")
                      .or().beginsWith("name","C")
                      .or().beginsWith("name","D")
                      .or().beginsWith("name","E")
                  .findAllSorted("name", Sort.ASCENDING);
```